# C# windows forms application

Tags: c#

```
private void button_Click(object sender, Event Args e)
{
   String a = comboBox1.Text.ToString();
   String b = comboBox2.Text.ToString();
   String C = comboBox3.Text.ToString();
}
```

> this is a function when I click on in 
>   if i change the value of the Combo Box I can't access to the new a,b,c that I want to use it another time 
>   can someone help me on this?

Comment: Did you look at SelectedIndexChanged event of ComboBox?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. You should probably add some more code and phrase your question in a way that is clear. Right now I don't understand what is calling button_click (I'm assuming you have a button as well as combo boxes), and why the new a,b,c aren't available. Unless they're going out of scope obviously...

Comment: I try to declare it out of the function same problem
 
how can i get the value from  (Selected Index Changed) to the button clicked  ??

Comment: where you want to use the values of variables a, b, c

Comment: In this function i post it

Comment: try to change the values of variables on the event as the answer

Comment: I don't understand u  sry

Comment: The problem is i want to user select index change on the button click

Comment: see the answer, if I understood what you want

Answer (score 0):

must declare the variables a, b, c in from out of function if you want to use variables outside the function button_click; try to change the values of variables on the event SelectedIndexChanged.

to simplify :

```
String a;
String b;
String C;

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    a = comboBox1.Text;
}

private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    b = comboBox2.Text;
}

private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    C = comboBox3.Text;
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //you can use variables a, b, c her..
}
```

Comment: you're right, just copy and paste from the question

Comment: Same problem if i do this can't see the variable a b c in button1_Click

Comment: what do you want to do with these variable a b c

Comment: the code of the response provides access to variables a b c in any function in the same class, Can you show one of this function ?

Comment: First time it works but if i make a button to empty the combobox and re enter the details in the combo box it works but it isn't a good way to do it

Comment: Normally the combo box is used to select the data and not to input. if you enter data in comboBox the event SelectedIndexChanged not work

Comment: I delet the combobox and reput it it work with selectedindexchanged  10x